# Check if UISwitch value changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a preference bundle where the specifiers are loaded from a `.plist` file. Some of the specifiers are `UISwitches`. How can I have a function called when the value of one of the `UISwitches` is changed?

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986150/uiswitch-doesnt-change-state

Comment: go through this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847059/objective-c-writing-uiswitch-state-in-a-plist-for-a-key?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

> To detect when changes to a preference value occur, apps can also register for the notification `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`. The shared NSUserDefaults object sends this notification to your app whenever it detects a change to a preference located in one of the persistent domains. You can use this notification to respond to changes that might impact your user interface. For example, you could use it to detect changes to the user’s preferred language and update your app content appropriately.

Register for this notification. When you receive it, check whether the switch has changed. Unfortunately, the notification doesn't tell you what change triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

`UISwitch`es are `UIControl`s so you can receive actions from them just like `UIButtons`.

Comment: I added an action to the switch in the .plist, but the action executes when the switch's cell is tapped, and not when the switch itself is toggled.

Comment: See that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098653/iphone-sdk-detecting-a-change-in-uiswitch